# Product of two compact spaces is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

I read the proof that uses tube lemma and I do not have any problem with it but I cannot see what is wrong with the proof that first came to my mind:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact spaces. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open covering of $X\times Y$. Then, $\bigcup_{U\in \mathcal{A}}{U}=X\times Y$. And $\pi_1(\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{A}}{U})=\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{A}}{\pi_1(U)}=X$, similarly $\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{A}}{\pi_2(U)}=Y$. Since $X$ is compact, there are finitely many $\pi_1(U)$'s and $\pi_2(U)$ that cover $X$ and $Y$. So the product of these finitely many sets covers $X\times Y$.

I presume that there is a mistake related to basic set theory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a mistake in this proof. The problem is that when you have your finite covers of $X$ and $Y$, it is true that the product of those open sets cover $X \times Y$ ; what is not true is that those products were in your original open cover!

Hope that helps,

Comment: Is there any way to fix this? I.e. to combine the finite covers so to get a finite subcover, or is this information for combining them ultimately lost by applying the projection maps?

Comment: @Stefan : The proof I know relies on Zorn's lemma and uses Alexander's subbase theorem, of which it is a corollary. I suggest you read it, it is not long! http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~cwildman/qualprep/tychonoff.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You find that the product of a finite number of those projected open sets covers your space, but what you have found is not a subcover.