# Why do we need tube lemma to prove the compactness of the product of two compact spaces?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I read the proof in Munkres' book *Topology* which uses the tube lemma but still thinking about an easier proof using basis of product topology :
$X \times Y$ has $$\{B_x \times B_y, B_x \times Y, X \times B_y \mid B_x \text{ and } B_y \text{ are basis of } X, Y\}$$ as basis.
Since both X and Y are compact, all their finite open sub-covers can be expressed in the same finite fashion using their basis considering that open sets can be derived from all unions of basis. Stating that, it seems easy to me that every open cover of $X \times Y$ has a finite sub-cover which can be derived from basis defined above. 
Obviously, I'm wrong somewhere but can't figure out where

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you elaborate on some of the concepts you are using: that would make your question accessible to many more users and might get you an answer quicker. Also, could you give the name of the book by Munkres?

Comment: Have you actually tried to write out such an argument in full detail? Here you seem merely to be saying that it looks as if it ought to work, but that doesn’t actually show that it does work.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it out. The only problem with the proposed proof seems the uncountability of the basis collection of underlying compact spaces. Am I wrong? Besides, I found a similar discussion which I cannot figure out the justiciation that 'they were in the original spaces'. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431582/product-of-two-compact-spaces-is-compact

Comment: @Gorkem: I don't understand "...all their finite open sub-covers can be expressed in the same finite fashion using their basis considering that open sets can be derived from all unions of basis." It doesn't make sense to speak of a "finite subcover" until you have a cover, and in the definition of compactness you have no control over the sets in the cover. Particularly, as in Patrick Da Silva's answer in the linked question, you don't know that the sets in an open cover are products of basis sets.

Comment: @user86418 Since we know that X and Y are compact, there are finite open covers for sure. Since the sets constituting the open cover are already associated with the bases via union relation, union of open sets covering the whole space is equivalent to covering with bases. I meant that. The issue in the link isn't directly relevant to what I talk about here. It's just another example of an easier proof which I don't understand the reason behind its invalidity.

Comment: Regarding "the only problem with the proposed proof seems the uncountability of…", whether a basis is countable or uncountable is irrelevant to the theorem in your question. On the other hand, if you carry out the suggestion of @BrianM.Scott, you may encounter other problems.

Comment: @Lee : I'm glad to hear if you have any foresights? I thought uncountability is an issue as some open sets might be obtained by infinite union of bases which leads to indifference between finite and infinite open covers from the basis' point of view.