# The Necessity of the Tube Lemma

Tags: general-topology

Munkres proves the following fact:

> The product of fintely many compact spaces is compact.

He does this via the [tube lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma). When I thought about this before reading his proof I argued in the following way:

The components are compact, so there are finte open covers. So for instance $X_1 \times ... \times X_N$ will for each coordinate have open covers $\mathcal{A}_{X_1},...,\mathcal{A}_{X_1}$. A member of the product cover will then be: $U_{X_1} \times U_{X_2} \times .. U_{X_N}$. There will be finitely many such open sets because a finite product of finite numbers is finite. Thus the product space is compact.

EDIT:
As I'm typing, Math.SE is linking a bunch of relevant posts: [Product of two compact spaces is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431582/product-of-two-compact-spaces-is-compact?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Can someone elaborate on the answer in this post? Am I producing something that isn't a member of any open cover of the product?

Comment: oh, I think I see the problem. I am producing finite covers. But I'm not checking that EVERY open cover of the product has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every space has a finite open cover; that's not the issue.

Compactness means we can reduce **any** open cover to a finite one. So you have to start with any old cover and reduce that and that's where the tube lemma could come in handy.